# Angular/Visual Studio: "ng is needed... npm is needed"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, windows-10

*Using: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022 17.1.0 (soon to be updated).*

I come from the age when I would just copy the JavaScript files of a library in a subfolder of my website/application, add some `<script...>` tag to the adequate pages and call it installed...

But right now I'm trying to initiate my first Angular 2+ project. I'm trying to start from "Standalone TypeScript Angular Project" template.
But Visual Studio won't create my project, it writes in red

```
ng is needed (...)
npm is needed (...)
```

So I checked how to install ng... I needed npm, I checked how to install npm... I read it's recommended to install it through nvm... so I installed nmv, then npm, then ng ( v16.15.1 )... but Visual Studio still won't create my project and keeps requiring `npm` and `ng`.

What am I missing?

*(I tried searching the Internet but mostly found a bunch of unrelated references and dead links.)*

---

Here are the precise things I ran so far:

```
nvm-setup.exe
```

(I installed it in a custom folder of D:\ as I want this kind of tools to go there.)

```
nvm install lts
```

This installed `npm` in a subfolder of my customer folder.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

This installed `ng` in a the same folder as npm + a subfolder.

---

I added '[...]/v16.15.1' (which contains `npm.cmd`, `ng.cmd` and `node.exe`) to the PATH "environment variable", but the problem remains unchanged.

---

Solved: after previous step, I needed to restart Visual Studio, but as I kept re-launching Visual Studio from Visual Studio Installer, it didn't work as a restart. Effectively closing the Installer and just relaunching Visual Studio refreshed things and it finally worked.

Comment: have you installed angular CLI? check the version with ng --version first, if it is installed check your node version with node -v, they both need to be installed

Comment: 'ng version' says that Angular CLI is version 14.0.2 . Node command is unknown. node -v syas "v16.15.1".
Is it expected that these command only work from where the are installed? Or should I find back that place make them system variables or something like this?

Comment: I added '[...]/v16.15.1' (which contains npm.cmd, ng.cmd and node.exe) to the PATH "environment variable", but the problem remains unchanged.

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio or the commandline tool with which you execute your angular program? Sometimes the tools need to "reload" the environment variables.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens: Thank you. I had restarted Visual Studio multiple times... but the thing was that I kept launching it from Visual Studio Installer, which I had not closed. Now that I really tried closing "everything", it work. Thx both for bringing my attention to some details I had missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: I needed to add the path that contains npm, ng and node to Windows "user and/or system Environment Variables".
And I also needed to restart Visual Studio (including closing Visual Studio Installer).